# Unexpected Setter Bar Behavior when Manipulate Nested in Dynamic Module

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Consider this code:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
y[t_] := t^3 + 5;

Manipulate[Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
{fcn, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}}]]
```

[image: SetterBar not working properly]

Why does the SetterBar created by Manipulate not highlight properly when either option is selected?

The same problem exists for other user interface elements, like a RadioButtonBar:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
y[t_] := t^3 + 5;

Manipulate[Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
{{fcn, x, "Graph Type"}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}, RadioButtonBar}]]
```

[image]

However, if you remove the DynamicModule, everything works as expected:

```
x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
y[t_] := t^3 + 5;

Manipulate[Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
{{fcn, x, "Graph Type"}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}}]
```

[image]

Also if you were to replace DynamicModule with Block or Module, everything works as expected:

```
Module[{x, y},
x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
y[t_] := t^3 + 5;

Manipulate[Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
{{fcn, x, "Graph Type"}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}}]]
```

Can anyone explain why this is, and how to fix it?

Comment: As the question is currently posed (it's been through several dramatic edits...hopefully my comment will still be relevant for a while), the code should work.  That it doesn't is a bug.  I've fixed it for a future release of Mathematica.

Comment: @JohnFultz - Thank you for your response. No further edits will be made to the question by me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you like explanations. I should point out that I will assume the reader is familiar with the element of *Mathematica*'s dynamic updating system, as described in the introductory tutorials
[[1]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html),
[[2]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html),,
but some of the issues touch on more advanced details found in
[[3]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html),
[[4]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html).

### What's going on

`Manipulate` does many things automatically, which can lead to issues when mixing it up too much with `Dynamic` and `DynamicModule`.  One of the issues is that `Manipulate` goes through the code it builds and any argument to a function in the control/variable specifications that has a symbol in the `` FE` `` context (seems to) get wrapped in `Dynamic`.  If the function does not handle that properly, then the code will break.

Another issue is that `DynamicModule` (and by implication `Manipulate`) does not create new `Unique`'d symbols when it is evaluated in the Kernel.  They get created when the `DynamicModule` is instantiated in the Front End (that is, when the Front End displays the `DynamicModule` output.
If `x` is a variable `x`in a `DynamicModule`, the Kernel substitutes the symbol `x$$` in the `DynamicModule` output that is returned to the Front End. That is the end of the first step.

The next step happens in the Front End, *when the Front End displays the `DynamicModule` output*.  In the Front End, `x$$` is converted to a symbol in the context `` FE` `` of the form `` FE`x$$nnn ``, where `nnn` are numerals appended to the name to make it unique, *when it is to be dynamically updated.*  Basically a symbol is to be dynamically updated when appears inside a `Dynamic`; but it might also be in a function that ultimately returns a `Dynamic` expression.  As the Front End instantiates the `DynamicModule`, it send this converted symbol to the Kernel for initialization together with the rest of the `DynamicModule` code.  In the example below, it turn out the symbols for `x` and `y` were initiated with `` Unset[FE`x$$14`] `` and `` FE`y$$14 = 2 `` are sent to the kernel.  ("Show Expression" output shown below.)

```
DynamicModule[{x, y = 2}, Dynamic@{x, y}]
(* {FE`x$$14, 2} *)
```

> ```
>  Cell[BoxData[ 
>   DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`x$$, $CellContext`y$$ = 2},
> ```
>
> DynamicBox[ToBoxes[{$CellContext`x$$, $CellContext`y$$}, StandardForm],
>           ImageSizeCache->{172., {3.608642578125, 14.}}],
>          DynamicModuleValues:>{}]], "Output",
>         CellChangeTimes->{3.584173863470374*^9, 3.584174940037945*^9}]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the next example below we can see that a variables `x` etc. are converted from a `$$` symbol to an `` FE` `` symbol when it appears inside `Dynamic`.  These are stored in the output `Cell` as `` $CellContext`x$$ ``, which the Front End converts when it displays the dynamic module.  The symbols not wrapped in a `Dynamic` are stored just as `x$$` without the `` $CellContext` `` context; and these are not converted.  (This is **not** the whole story on when they are converted, by the way.)  In fact these were evaluated in the Kernel when the `DynamicModule` was first evaluated.  This is why a `2` was returned instead of `y$$` in the second sublist.  When `Dynamic@{x, y}` is evaluated in the Kernel, it is basically passed right back to the Front End (actually in a `DynamicBox` with `x$$`, `y$$`), which will it evaluate when it gets ready to display the expression in the output.  At that point, the `` FE` `` symbols are substituted.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y}, y = 2; {Dynamic@{x, y}, {x, y}, Hold[y], Dynamic@Hold[y]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we see that the variable `x` in the code is translated to two distinct variables in the output.

The reason this is an issue for the OP's code has to do with the values that are the basis for the `SetterBar`.  Are they going to be `x$$`, `y$$` or `` FE`x$$nnn ``, `` FE`y$$nnn ``?  We've seen that both are possible.  If the first, then the `SetterBar` won't highlight, even though it seems to set `fcn` properly, because when `fcn = x` is executed inside the `Dynamic[fcn]` that is passed to the `SetterBar`, `fcn` will be set to `` FE`x$$nnn `` after conversion by the Front End.  This value will not match the `x$$` passed to `SetterBar`, and the `SetterBar` will not be highlighted.  This is the problem with the nonworking `Manipulate`s in the question.  Fix this and the `Manipulate` should work (see "Fixes" below).

A rather minor issue is that `Manipulate` does not initialize a variable the way one might expect with the declaration

```
{var, {d1 -> "label 1", d2 -> "label 2", ...}}
```

Instead of `var = d1`, we get `var = d1 -> "label 1"`.  You have to explicitly initialize `var` with

```
{{var, d1}, {d1 -> "label 1", d2 -> "label 2", ...}}
```

I say it's a minor issue because if `d1` is a `Manipulate` variable, then there is still another issue having to do with how `Manipulate` builds the code for the `SetterBar`.

### Fixes

In addition to the other fine answers, here are some other options.  There are a few I wouldn't recommend (and so indicated), but are included for illustration purposes.  The other methods I've used in practice, depending on what was convenient in a given situation.

**Dynamic.**
This fix occurred to me while thinking through the reasoning above.  I would not recommend it in practice, although its working correctly is consistent with the explanation.

However, if you try to initialize `fcn` with `{{fcn, x}, ...}` it gets initialized to `y` (the last element in the list).  I do not know why.  In the current form `fcn` will be initialized to `{x -> "Square", ...}`; you could uncomment the `If` statement to make a one-time initialization.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
 y[t_] := t^3 + 5;
 Manipulate[
  (*If[MatchQ[fcn, _List], fcn = x];*)
  Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
  {fcn, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}, Dynamic @ SetterBar[#1, First@#2] &}]]
```

**Pure Functions.**

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
 {{fcn, #^2 + 5 &}, {#^2 + 5 & -> "Square", #^3 + 5 & -> "Cubic"}}]
```

**Use expressions (three ways)**

*Global variables*

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[fcn, {t, -5, 5}],
 {{fcn, t^2 + 5}, {t^2 + 5 -> "Square", t^3 + 5 -> "Cubic"}}]
```

*Local Kernel variables*

```
Module[{t},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[fcn, {t, -5, 5}],
  {{fcn, t^2 + 5}, {t^2 + 5 -> "Square", t^3 + 5 -> "Cubic"}}]
 ]
```

*Local `Manipulate` variables.*  This way `SetterBar` must be explicitly specified; otherwise you get a slider for `fcn`.  This inexplicable behavior has to do with what's going on under the hood of `Manipulate`, and I don't know what's going on under the hood of `Manipulate`.  It hinges on `t` being one of the `Manipulate` variables, but I cannot explain why or how.  It suggests that this may not be the most reliable solution, but it works here.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[fcn, {t, -5, 5}],
 {{fcn, t^2 + 5}, {t^2 + 5 -> "Square", t^3 + 5 -> "Cubic"}, SetterBar},
 {{t, t}, None}]
```

**Localize function symbols in `Module`,** which you did in one of your examples.  I suggest initializing them in the `Manipulate`.

```
Module[{x, y},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}],
  {{fcn, x}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}},
  Initialization :> (
    x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
    y[t_] := t^3 + 5)]
 ]
```

**Rules**

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[name[t] /. nameToFcn], {t, -5, 5}],
 {{name, "x", "function"}, {"x" -> "Square", "y" -> "Cubic"}},
 {{x, x}, ControlType -> None},
 {{y, y}, ControlType -> None},
 {nameToFcn, ControlType -> None},
 Initialization :> (
   x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
   y[t_] := t^3 + 5;
   nameToFcn = {"x" -> x, "y" -> y})]
```

**Play the Front End for a sucker:** Create the symbol you need.  Probably not a good solution, but interesting.  This avoids having a `DynamicModule` variable in the data `{"x$$" -> "Square", "y$$" -> "Cubic"}` that is passed to `SetterBar`, so `Manipulate` passes it as is.  (The body of a `Manipulate` is wrapped in `Dynamic` automatically.)

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
 y[t_] := t^3 + 5;
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[Symbol[fcn][t]], {t, -5, 5}],
  {{fcn, "x$$"}, {"x$$" -> "Square", "y$$" -> "Cubic"}}]]
```

**`DynamicModule` with `OwnValues`.**
(Edit per request in comment.)

Instead of `UpValues`, `x[t_] :=..`, if we use `OwnValues`, `x = ..`, together with our own `SetterBar` function, we can make `DynamicModule` work with `Manipulate` in this case:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[fcn[t]], {t, -5, 5}],
  {{fcn, x}, 
   SetterBar[Dynamic@fcn, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}] &},
  Initialization :> (
    x := t \[Function] t^2 + 5;
    y := t \[Function] t^3 + 5)]
 ]
```

But it's simpler to `Manipulate` as our `DynamicModule` -- it's more or less the same, but without the nesting which makes things less complicated (and more predictable).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[fcn[t]], {t, -5, 5}],
 {{fcn, x}, SetterBar[Dynamic@fcn, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}] &},
 {x, ControlType -> None}, {y, ControlType -> None},
 Initialization :> (
   x = t \[Function] t^2 + 5;
   y = t \[Function] t^3 + 5)]
```

The issue as explained above really lies in passing the right values to `SetterBar` in the list `{value -> label, ..}`.  Because `SetterBar` is inside a `Function` (`SetterBar[..] &`), the `SetterBar` is not evaluated until the dynamic module is instantiated by the Front End.  So the variables `x` and `y` in the second argument will be evaluated at that time, when they will be converted to the form `` FE`x$nnn ``.

### Seeing what `SetterBar` is getting

I wrote a little helper control that stored some of the arguments to help me see how `Manipulate` handled things.  A declaration of the form

```
{var, list, function}
```

results in `function[Dynamic[var], {list}]` or  `function[Dynamic[var], {Dynamic[list]}]`, depending on whether `Manipulate` thinks the extra `Dynamic` is helpful.  This seems to happen when `list` contains `Manipulate` variables.  You have to strip the `Dynamic` off, though, or `SetterBar` won't recognize it as a valid argument.  But that's part of the problem.  The values are going to be of the form `x$$`, not `` FE`x$$nnn ``, and the `SetterBar` won't highlight.  Presumably `Manipulate` put `Dynamic` around them to ensure they be converted properly.

```
Clear[mySB];
mySB[Dynamic[x_], {Dynamic[vals_]}] :=
  (setterx = Hold[x]; settervals = Dynamic[vals]; 
   SetterBar[Dynamic[x, (updatex = Hold[x]; x = #) &], vals]);
mySB[Dynamic[x_], {vals_}] := (setterx = Hold[x]; settervals = vals; 
   RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[x, (updatex = Hold[x]; x = #) &], vals]);
```

Interestingly, one can see that while `fcn$$` is passed as an argument to the control, it is `` FE`fcn$$nnnn `` that is updated dynamically.  (Click on a control to cause `updatex` to be set.)

```
Manipulate[
 fcn,
 {{fcn, x}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}, mySB[##] &},
 {{x, x}, ControlType -> None},
 {{y, y}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {fcn}
 ]
(* output omitted *)

settervals // FullForm
setterx
updatex
(* Dynamic[List[Rule[x$$, "Square"], Rule[y$$, "Cubic"]]] *)
(* Hold[fcn$$] *)
(* Hold[FE`fcn$$2501] *)
```

When the `x`, `y` are put in an outer `DynamicModule`, `Manipulate` does not wrap them in `Dynamic`.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Manipulate[
  fcn,
  {{fcn, x}, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}, (mySB[##]) &},
  TrackedSymbols :> {fcn}
  ]
 ]
(* output omitted *)

settervals // FullForm
setterx
updatex
(* List[Rule[x$$, "Square"], Rule[y$$, "Cubic"]] *)
(* Hold[fcn$$] *)    
(* Hold[FE`fcn$$2513] *)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Well done!

Comment: Michael, I struggled understanding some things that you said (being so new to Mathematica) that may of helped understanding, but I still have the following problem: Under "fixes", the only one that has a DynamicModule in the solution is the one you didn't recommend in practice, and it still has initialization problems. I want to use DynamicModule so that the variables (and their states) are stored independent of the kernel/session. Any ideas how to address this concern?

Comment: @tjm167us  `Dynamic` is hard to understand, so no worries. :)  The "Pure Functions", "Rules", and "Use expressions" should be independent of the kernel/session (perhaps avoid the `Module` ones - there's a sneaky bug you might run into).  If you can't make those work for you, I added another one with `DynamicModule`.  If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to say more about how ultimate goal.  Also, I also tried to clarify the explanation, but perhaps it would be better to start with the link tutorials. Godd luck!

Comment: This answer says many things which are correct, but some things which are either incorrect or misleading. Chief among them is the notion that I have ever said that mixing `Dynamic` and/or `DynamicModule` with `Manipulate` is a bad idea. I have never said or implied that. Yes, it is true that this particular usage of `DynamicModule` with `Manipulate` does not work, but it's a fluke, not a sign of a systemic issue or misunderstanding. Attempts to mix `Module` and `Manipulate`, on the other hand, inevitably result from a systemic misunderstanding of the system and should be avoided entirely.

Comment: For anyone who cares about the underlying implementational details mentioned here (which should *not* be necessary or relied upon for top-level use of `DynamicModule`), it's useful to explain why variables have two representations.  Imagine if you take a `DynamicModule` object and copy it.  It should be a precise copy, which includes copying the variable names precisely.  And the FE has no problem isolating duplicate variable names in different instances of `DynamicModule`.  But, sometimes, to resolve a `Dynamic`, the FE must send something to the kernel. (to be continued)

Comment: Different `DynamicModule` instances must have their variables tracked separately in the kernel.  Why doesn't the kernel just use the same names and clean everything up afterwards?  Because the kernel participates in the system which determines when a `Dynamic` needs to be updated.  It does so by tracking changes to named variables.  So these variables have to have a kernel footprint.  And if there are two identical `DynamicModule`s hanging about, we're going to have to differentiate their variables.  So, we chose to do so using a name decoration not unlike the one `Module` uses.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks for replying.  I was hoping you would, esp. if I was inaccurate.  I think I'll just take that part out.  Your reading of it is not what I really meant to say, and I apologize for the misleading paraphrase. I was acknowledging Nasser's quote and meant only to pay you and him your all's due.

Comment: Incidentally, the `Dynamic` solution is an intriguing solution, and I don't see any reason to disrecommend it in your answer.  Perhaps somebody will find some stupid bug to make me eat those words.  But I wouldn't argue against the solution on principle.

Comment: @JohnFultz I think I merely lacked confidence to recommend it, and preferred simpler or at least more familiar solutions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I wanted to express my appreciation for the time you committed to helping me answer the question. I know your post took a good bit of thought and effort!

Answer (score 8):

`Module variables should *never* appear inside Dynamics or Manipulates internal to that Module.` [John Fultz, 2011]

Since `Manipulate` itself is `DynamicModule` Hence you effectively have this:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y}, x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
 y[t_] := t^3 + 5;
 Manipulate[
  Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}], {fcn, {x -> "Square", y -> "Cubic"}}]]
```

turned to

```
 DynamicModule[{x, y}, x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
  y[t_] := t^3 + 5;
  DynamicModule[{fcn = FE`x$$12 -> "Square"}, Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}]]]
```

You can see how `Manipulate` became a `DynamicModule` by hitting the small `+` on the top corner of the `Manipulate` and clicking `Paste snapshot`.

So, what does this mean, you ask? Well, you hit one of the bad rules of thumbs in `Dynamics`, you had a `Module` variable `x` appears inside a `Dynamic` internal to that `Module`, i.e. you have this pattern:

```
 Module[{a}, Dynamic[a]]
```

Mixing `Dynamics` inside `Dynamics` is a tricky thing. I just use the famous John Fultz rules on this from his post on sept 2011, and I never have problems after that (well, almost never :). [Here are the rules](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ)

> I could explain in some considerable detail exactly what's going on
>   here (and it would be considerable), but it might be more useful and
>   straightforward to give you a very simple rule...
>
> Module variables should *never* appear inside Dynamics or Manipulates
>   internal to that Module.
>
> To be clear with some examples (all using Dynamic, but they could
>   equally well use Manipulate, which is implemented using Dynamic)...
>
> (* OK *) Dynamic[Module[{a}, a]]
>
> (* OK *) Module[{a},
>                   (* expression involving a*);
>                   Dynamic[(* expression *not* involving a *)]
>
> (* BAD *) Module[{a}, Dynamic[a]]
>
> In fact, this rule is so straightforward and universal, there's no
>   reason that we shouldn't have some advisory syntax highlighting which
>   points out the badness...I intend to do this for a future release.

Comment: It occurred to me when looking at this that I neglected to add syntax coloring for `Module`/`Manipulate` conflicts.  I.e., for the purpose of syntax coloring scope conflicts, Mathematica should treat the first argument of `Manipulate` exactly as if it were the first argument of `Dynamic`.  Fixing that for a future version...

Answer (score 1):

Nasser gives a learned discussion of why, but he doesn't tell how to fix it. It's easy:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[fcn[t], {t, -5, 5}], 
  {{fcn, x, "function"}, {x -> "Quadratic", y -> "Cubic"}},
  Initialization :> (
    x[t_] := t^2 + 5;
    y[t_] := t^3 + 5)]
```

Note that I made a small modification to your setter bar specification. In this form the `Manipulate` will start up with "Quadratic" choice selected.