# Manipulate inside Module - "Order of evaluation conflicts"

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, scoping

In this example, `Manipulate` is contained within a `Module`:

```
Module[{plots},
 plots = Table[x^n, {n, 1, 5}];
 Manipulate[
  Plot[plots[[i]], {x, 0, 1}],
  {i, 1, 5, 1}]
 ]
```

The code works as expected, but Mathematica highlights `plots` inside `Manipulate` as red, with the message "Order of evaluation conflicts":

[image]

[image]

Is there actually a problem here if the code works anyway?
Why is Mathematica doing this?

Comment: Having `Manipulate` or `Dynamic` inside of `Module` is bad practice. You can find the reasons in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29461/18476).

Comment: Mma v9 does not complain ...

Comment: Ok I understand now, the issue is that Manipulate stores across sessions and so the Module is leaky. I think the syntax colouring message might be wrong though... shouldn't it be something about going out of scope?

Comment: @belisarius "It occurred to me when looking at this that I neglected to add syntax coloring for Module/Manipulate conflicts... Fixing that for a future version" - J. Fultz 2013 in a comment to the answer Karsten linked to first.

Comment: @Pickett Pure genius :)