# Dynamic variables inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I have a problem while playing with a `Dynamic` `Slider` inside a `Manipulate`. The code looks like this:

```
Manipulate[
Module[{efl, swath, fov, d1, R1, R2, α},

efl = (1 10^-3) (h p)/gsd;

swath = (1 10^-3) np gsd;

fov = (1/Degree) 2 ArcTan[swath/(2 h)];

d1 = FindRoot[
 1.0 - (1 10^-3) (λ h)/(
   x grd) (1 + ((x p)/(λ efl))^1.35)^(1/1.35), {x, 
  1 10^-3}, MaxIterations -> 100][[1, 2]];

R1 = -2 (Δ efl)/((-Δ + e) - efl);

R2 = 2.0 ((-Δ + e) (R1/2.0 - Δ))/(R1/
  2.0 - 2.0 Δ + e);

Grid[{{"α", 
  Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic[α], {-(fov/2), fov/2, fov/10}, 
 AutoAction -> False], 
  Dynamic[α]}}]

  ],

Grid[{
  {Row[{Control[{{λ, 0.1, "Wavelenght [μm]"}, 
    Range[0.1, 1.0, 0.1]}], Spacer[40], 
  Control[{{h, 400, "Altitude [Km]"}, Range[400, 700, 50] }], 
  Spacer[40], 
  Control[{{gsd, 0.3, "GSD [m]"}, Range[0.3, 5.0, 0.1] }], 
  Spacer[40], 
  Control[{{p, 2, "Pixel Pitch [μm]"}, 
    Range[2.0, 15.0, 1.0]}], Spacer[40], 
  Control[{{np, 2000, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(p\)]\) [U.A]"},
     Range[2000, 12000, 1000] }]}], Spacer[40]},

  {},

  {Grid[{{"GRD", 
     Dynamic@Slider[
     Dynamic[grd], {gsd (1 + (1 10^-3 (λ h)/(
           12.0 gsd))^1.35)^(1/1.35) , 10 gsd}, 
     AutoAction -> False], Dynamic[grd]}}]},

  {},

  {Row[{Control[{{Δ, -0.5, "Dist. P-S [m]"}, 
    Range[-0.5, -0.1, 0.02]}], Spacer[40], 
  Control[{{e0, 0.01, "Focus Distance [m]"}, 
    Range[0.01, 0.1, 0.01]}]}]}}], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

The problem is in the definition of α. With `Manipulate` I can control the basic parameter for the calculation of `efl`, `swath`, `fov`, `d1`, `R1` and `R2`. The limits for the `Slider` which varies α depends on the variable `fov`. Dont know why but Mathematica doesnt like the way I'm defining this variable and highlights in red the `fov` parameter inside the Dynamic@Slider of `α`. What I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work as expected? Your code contains undefined symbols. If the only issue is the red coloring, than change `Module` to `DynamicModule`. The reason for the syntax highlighting is that one should not use ``Module` variables inside `Dynamic`. Ref.: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29461/18476

Comment: @Karsten7. Excellent!. That solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Variables inside `Dynamic[]` should not be `Module` variables, when the scope of the `Module` contains the `Dynamic`. `Dynamic[Module[{x},f[x]]]` is OK, but not `Module[{x}, Dynamic[f[x]]]`.  Using `DynamicModule[]` instead as @Karsten suggests is OK, but it might not work the way you want.  It will reset `α` every time a control is changed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 right know I need `α` to change when the variable fov changes because fov sets the limits of `α`.

Comment: OK. Do you mind if `α` is reset when `λ`, `Δ`, or `e0` changes, even though `fov` is unaltered?

Comment: Oh didnt see that. How can I prevent this to happen? @MichaelE2

Comment: Another thing is that the variables that are defined inside the `Grid` are used in the subsequent part of the code but I cant end this command with `;` because I need the bars to be printed when the program is executed. This is a problem because if I write another equation below `Grid` without the semicolon at the end the programs gives me `Null` at the output. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to put the alpha variable up in the control section of the Manipulate?

Comment: Thanks for the responde @bills. There is a little problem with `alpha` being defined in the control section because there is a problem with the limits depending on the variable `fov` which is defined inside the code. It gives any value to `alpha` not related to te actual value of `fov`

Comment: Hey guys why when I put the Dynamic control of a variable (for example `α` in the previous code) whenever I try to operate with this variable I get an error and if I want to print `α` as output Mathematica return this symbol: `α$$`. Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution may be to place the alpha slider up in the control area (along with all the other controls). Sliders and other controllers in a Manipulate can have dependent endpoints. Note how the range of the alpha slider changes dynamically with the variable `fov`. When a variable is reset that causes alpha to be outside the endpoints, alpha is reset by the If statement.

```
Manipulate[Module[{efl, swath, fov, d1, R1, R2},
  efl = (1 10^-3) (h p)/gsd;
  swath = (1 10^-3) np gsd;
  fov = (1/Degree) 2 ArcTan[swath/(2 h)];
  end = Range[-fov/2, fov/2, fov/10];
  If[\[Alpha] < Min[end] || \[Alpha] > Max[end], alpha = fov/2];
  d1 = FindRoot[1.0 - (1 10^-3) (\[Lambda] h)/(x grd) (1 + ((x p)/(\[Lambda] efl))^1.35)^(1/1.35), {x, 1 10^-3}, MaxIterations -> 100][[1, 2]];
  R1 = -2 (\[CapitalDelta] efl)/((-\[CapitalDelta] + e) - efl);
  R2 = 2.0 ((-\[CapitalDelta] + e) (R1/2.0 - \[CapitalDelta]))/(R1/
        2.0 - 2.0 \[CapitalDelta] + e);
  {\[Alpha], end}], 
 Grid[{{Row[{Control[{{\[Lambda], 0.1, "Wavelenght [\[Mu]m]"}, 
        Range[0.1, 1.0, 0.1]}], Spacer[40], 
      Control[{{h, 400, "Altitude [Km]"}, Range[400, 700, 50]}], 
      Spacer[40],
      Control[{{\[Alpha], 0.1, "alpha"}, Dynamic[end]}], Spacer[20], 
      Control[{{gsd, 0.3, "GSD [m]"}, Range[0.3, 5.0, 0.1]}], Spacer[40], 
      Control[{{p, 2, "Pixel Pitch [\[Mu]m]"}, 
        Range[2.0, 15.0, 1.0]}], Spacer[40], 
      Control[{{np, 2000, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(p\)]\) [U.A]"}, Range[2000, 12000, 1000]}]}], Spacer[40]}, {}, 
     {Grid[{{"GRD", Dynamic@Slider[
         Dynamic[grd], {gsd (1 + (1 10^-3 (\[Lambda] h)/(12.0 gsd))^1.35)^(1/1.35), 10 gsd}, AutoAction -> False], 
       Dynamic[grd]}}]}, {}, {Row[{Control[{{\[CapitalDelta], -0.5, 
         "Dist. P-S [m]"}, Range[-0.5, -0.1, 0.02]}], Spacer[40], 
      Control[{{e0, 0.01, "Focus Distance [m]"}, 
        Range[0.01, 0.1, 0.01]}]}]}}], SaveDefinitions -> False]
```

Comment: Thanks @bills for your explanation. It works and avoids the reset of `alpha` every time a variable different from `fov` is changed.